# Java recursive file list returns null for a spaced name folder

Tags: java, file

Trying to list recursively all the files and folders from a path.

All works perfectly until I get a spaced folder name. In this case when I try to get the list of Files with `f.list()` or `f.listFiles()`, both return `null`.
As I'm testing on Windows, I tried to replace all spaces by '%20' which ended with the same result.

The documentation says :

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or
>   if an I/O error occurs.

How can I list files and folders for a spaced folder name?

```java
String path = "c:/Users/Ioman/AppData/Local/Archivos temporales de Internet";
File f = new File(path);
fileNames(f);

private void fileNames(File f) {
    System.out.println("Folder name : " + f.getAbsolutePath());
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            fileNames(file);
        } else {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me with all folders - space or not in the names.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with folder names with spaces also. But I recommend to use easier way from Java 8 and see if this works.

```
  Files.find(Paths.get(path),
            Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            (filePath, fileAttr) -> fileAttr.isRegularFile())
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Ok, tried it but had same problem, but I found why.
The file I am trying to access is a simbolic link (shown as <Junction> in Windows).  Calling methods exist() or isDirectory() returns true, but when I tried to call listFiles(), it returns null.  This is because it uses the path given by toAbsolutePath() and founds nothing there.  Is not even listed with a simple 'dir' command in the CMD, but you can get in with a 'cd' command.
I solved using File.toPath().toRealPath().

Thx all for the replies.